# How to get method to recognize else part of if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I've made a street craps game and have an error checker in the beginning to make sure the input is valid, I put it in an if statement and then have the rest of the code (for valid inputs) as the else but it isn't recognizing the else part when the user puts in a valid number.

```
public void play() { //method
    System.out.println("Please pick a number.");
    guess = scan.nextInt();
    if (guess == 7 || guess == 1 || guess == 0 || guess > 12) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, that is an invalid input, please choose another number.");
        guess = scan.nextInt();
    } else {
        int roll = dieOne.roll();
        int roll2 = dieTwo.roll();
        int rollSums = roll + roll2;
        System.out.println(roll + "+" + roll2);
        while (rollSums != 7) {
            if (guess == rollSums) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations, you win! Your number was rolled before a seven was rolled!");
                rollSums = 7;
                guess = 7;
            } else {
                roll = dieOne.roll();
                roll2 = dieTwo.roll();
                rollSums = roll + roll2;
                System.out.println(roll + "+" + roll2);
            }
        }
        if (rollSums != guess) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, your number was not rolled before a seven was rolled.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to execute the if part until the if condition is not satisfied, and then you want to execute the else part. If this is what you want you need to execute the if part as a while loop, and the else part as code after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need a while loop to make sure you get a good input first, and then do the game logic, like this:

```
    int guess = scan.nextInt();
    while (guess == 7 || guess == 1 || guess == 0 || guess > 12){
        System.out.println("Sorry, that is an invalid input, please choose another number.");
        guess = scan.nextInt();
    } 

    //Game Logic (Stuff in else section)
```